# Can't make my C++ program standalone

Tags: c++, windows, dll, codeblocks, libcurl

This question has been asked in here but it is not a duplicate as i can't reach a solution based on that answer my problem,is:

I am trying to have my program statically built,in order to make a standalone executable out of it(by embedding the dlls) i can't seem to make that happen,i tried to include static & static-libgcc in the other options in build options tab,but it still doesn't make any difference i still have to have the dlls in the same folder as my executable so it could work

PS: I don't want the installer solution,i need it to be a standalone,even if it could make it larger in size.

I can provide with a list of the dlls if needed.

The program is a C++ consloe app,on codeblocks,windows OS,the dlls are libcurl dlls. I tried the solution on this answer [Adding static libcurl to Code::Blocks IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243638/adding-static-libcurl-to-codeblocks-ide) but i have this error  `undefined references to __chkstk_ms'` thus i can no longer even build the program,and even more we are not using the same libcurl version,am using curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32

My question is also different from this [using libcurl without dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411259/using-libcurl-without-dll) because we don't have the same errors,the same IDE,same version of libcurl,and the answer i posted above is the closest to mine,i just couldn't make it work,i had more errors,and couldn't even build,as i have mentionned,this is not a duplicate question hence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using libcurl without dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411259/using-libcurl-without-dll)

Comment: No its not,it doesn't have a picked answer + neither the libcurl versions,neither the IDE,nor the errors match.Not even close.

Comment: The symbol `__chkstk_ms` is defined by *libgcc*, a GCC-4.x-specific library incompatible with GCC-3.x. You need to install MinGW 4.6.x to fix this. The MinGW compiler that comes with Code::Blocks is too old, and should best be uninstalled. You may want to consider getting [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) instead. Same price, but without the hassles. And it may convince you to start thinking about Unicode (which Code::Blocks to this date doesn't).

Comment: why does this problem only appear when i try this solution?