# How to include libcurl into my custom dll

Tags: c++, dll, libcurl

I have been using libcurl to handle APIs in my c++ script which is a dll. I am struggling to include libcurl into my dll(meaning i want libcurl to be included into my dll after build, currently I am getting a separate dll for libcurl and another dll for my script. trying to avoid multiple dlls), Is there a way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using libcurl without dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411259/using-libcurl-without-dll)

Comment: Did you statically build libcurl and of its dependencies?

Comment: This may help: [https://curl.se/mail/lib-2019-11/0078.html](https://curl.se/mail/lib-2019-11/0078.html)