# Building LibCurl with OpenSSL causes linker errors

Tags: c++, curl, static-libraries, libcurl

I have been trying to build LibCurl with SSL support for 2 days now, and I have followed about every guide on the internet, and google'd errors for hours. I finally got it to compile fine, but when I link to it, I am getting the linker errors listed below.

I am building with...

```
nmake -f Makefile.vc9 OPENSSL_PATH=c:\dev_mms\openSSL RTLIBCFG=static CFG=release-ssl
```

The following errors, when I google'd them said something about the OpenSSL libs not being linked to properly, but I looked at Makefile.vc9, and it definitely is including the proper libs for OpenSSL. Here are the linker errors (I removed about 50 of them just to shorten it), what can I do to resolve these?

```
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_status referenced in function _rand_enough
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_file_name referenced in function _ossl_seed
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_load_file referenced in function _ossl_seed
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_check_private_key referenced in function _cert_stuff
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_free referenced in function _cert_stuff
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BN_num_bits referenced in function _get_cert_chain
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_serialNumber referenced in function _get_cert_chain
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_INTEGER_get referenced in function _get_cert_chain
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_issuer_name referenced in function _get_cert_chain
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_peer_cert_chain referenced in function _get_cert_chain
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_verify_cert_error_string referenced in function _servercert
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_verify_result referenced in function _servercert
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_check_issued referenced in function _servercert
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PEM_read_X509 referenced in function _servercert
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_free referenced in function _servercert
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_peer_certificate referenced in function _servercert
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get1_session referenced in function _ossl_connect_step3
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_pending referenced in function _Curl_ossl_data_pending
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_write referenced in function _ossl_send
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSLeay referenced in function _Curl_ossl_version
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DES_set_key referenced in function _setup_des_key
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DES_set_odd_parity referenced in function _setup_des_key
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DES_ecb_encrypt referenced in function _lm_resp
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD4_Final referenced in function _mk_nt_hash
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD4_Update referenced in function _mk_nt_hash
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD4_Init referenced in function _mk_nt_hash
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Final referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm
1>libcurl.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Final
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Update referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm
1>libcurl.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Update
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Init referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm
1>libcurl.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Init
1>libcurl.lib(http_ntlm.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _RAND_bytes referenced in function _Curl_output_ntlm
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add

```
 libeay32.lib ssleay32.lib
```

To additional dependencies in the project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the directions in the answer to Question 197444 ([building libcurl with ssl support on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197444/building-libcurl-with-ssl-support-on-windows)) and it works like a dream.

Give those a shot and let me know how it goes.