# Which library to use for http?

Tags: c

I was wondering which library are available for http sending and receiving in C?

I would like to create a program that will load a website. A program that will load Yahoo with a click of a button. A program that will promote me for search term and when I enter it and it will go to the first results of Google and display the information.

Comment: Are you specifically concerned about [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https) (encrypted HTTP) or did you mean plain ol' [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http)?

Comment: I meant HTTP. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Does it need to be C, can it be C++? Do you care what it is written in?

Comment: I only know some basic programming with C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/).

There is a demo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

size_t write_func(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, ptr, size*nmemb); 
        return size*nmemb;
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
        CURL *curl;
        if (argv != 2) {
                return 0;
        }
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (!curl) {
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_init error");
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, argc[1]);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_func);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let say I tried to compile this on a windows machine but it give me an error `fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

Comment: That's not a reason to not use it. Give more info, @LearningC.

Comment: @Learning C, maybe this link will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197444/building-libcurl-with-ssl-support-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Tried [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html)?

[Here are some examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).