# Building libCURL with OpenSSL for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, build, openssl, libcurl

I'm trying to compile and build libCURL 7.49.1 with OpenSSL 1.0.2 support for use in Visual Studio 2013 on Win 64. I've found a couple of answers that provide  instructions on how to do this ([Building libcurl with SSL support on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197444/building-libcurl-with-ssl-support-on-windows)), but rather than following a set of instructions by rote I'd like to understand a bit more about what's going on.

My understanding of what means to "compile and build libCURL with OpenSSL support" is that I'm going to get the source code for the libCURL project, and then compile/build it using some kind of make file provided by the developers. I'm going to let the build tool I'm going to use to build libCURL know that it should include openSSL as a dependency. Is that about right for a high-level picture of what's going on? Also, what special steps do I need to build for use in Visual Studio rather than some other IDE?

To include another library as a dependency, the libCURL documentation says:

```
If you wish to support zlib, openssl, c-ares, ssh2, you will have to download
   them separately and copy them to the deps directory as shown below:

   somedirectory\
    |_curl-src
    | |_winbuild
    |
    |_deps
      |_ lib
      |_ include
      |_ bin
```

What exactly do I need to put in the lib, include and bin folders? Presumably lib will get the OpenSSL .lib files, the include folder will get all the OpenSSL header files, and the bin folder will include the OpenSSL .dlls and .exe? Presumably those files will be generated after I successfully build OpenSSL. Am I missing anything?

Comment: [cURL has an INSTALL document](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html). You can find it by going to the [cURL source code](http://github.com/curl/curl) and following the link titled *Find out how to install Curl by reading the INSTALL document*. [OpenSSL has an INSTALL document](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL) and a [NOTES.WIN](http://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.WIN). You can find it by going to the [OpenSSL source code](http://github.com/openssl/openssl). You should probably start by reading them.

Comment: I've looked at INSTALL.WIN64 for OpenSSL and BUILD.WINDOWS for libCURL. They mostly seem to contain "run these commands" type of instructions. I'll have a look at the documents you linked, but I'm looking more for a succinct overview rather than a link to detailed documentation.

Comment: Please check: https://gist.github.com/Mecanik/06aa38b638316d8840b685eb1474ad7d