# After Building OpenSSL with VS2017 getting some Link Errors. " OPENSSL_init_ssl referenced in function _main "?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, openssl

```
  #include "pch.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <openssl\ssl.h>
  #include <openssl\err.h>
  #include <openssl\conf.h>
  int main()
   {
       SSL_library_init();
       SSL_load_error_strings();
    }
```

OpenSSL DLL Throws some errors

Getting the following error after built openssl in vs2017

Severity        Code        Description        Project        File        Line        Suppression State
Error        LNK2019        unresolved external symbol _OPENSSL_init_ssl referenced in function _main

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Fixed it with a new compiled libraries . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source :  [Building libcurl with SSL support on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197444/building-libcurl-with-ssl-support-on-windows/5129202#5129202)

Thanks Mr. https://stackoverflow.com/users/519376/vtellier

I have followed the following instructions with slight modifications and it worked fine for VS2017 with latest OpenSSL

In my case follow the curl README file was enough.
My configuration is the following:

- Visual Studio 2017

  Static library

  Win64

  curl version 7.57.0

  OpenSSL 1.0.2

**Compilation of libCurl**

Download libcurl source there: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

compress the file and go to the folder curl-7.57.0\projects

Open the README file and follow the instructions, this lead me to do the following:

- Downloaded OpenSSL 
         Extract it and rename it to openssl, put it aside the curl folder, this is important as you'll open the VS project that expect
  to find openssl there.
        Install Perl
        Execute the utility build-openssl.bat to perform the compilation of openSSL. With my settings this became the following:
        \build-openssl.bat vc14 x64 release ....\openssl\
        just runs .\build-openssl.bat -help to know more about the parameters.
        After that you can see OpenSSL has been compiled as you got a new folder here: openssl\build\Win64

  Open the Visual Studio project
  curl-7.57.0\projects\Windows\VC14\curl-all.sln

  Be sure to set the visual studio project to the build configuration
  you need (LIB Release - LIB OpenSSL in my case)

  Build all . The library is located at
  curl-7.57.0\build\Win64\VC14\LIB Release - L

Answer (score 0):

For OpenSSL 1.0, building a program on Windows require linking with `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib`. You can find these libraries in the out32dll or out32 folder of your OpenSSL folder depending on how you built it.  OpenSSL 1.1 might have a different lib name for these libraries.

Also, if you built these libraries as DLLs, you need to copy over libeay32.**dll** and ssleay32.**dll** into the same folder as your EXE or have them in your PATH in order for the program to run.

Comment: Fixed it with a new compiled libraries . Thanks :)